# Changing Code in GameManager.cs for Unity Game Works in Editor But Not in Compiled Build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My player originally spawned slightly below the floor causing my player to fall through the floor and infinitely fall downward into nothingness.

I changed this line of code in `GameManager.cs` from
`_player.transform.localPosition = RemapTileCoordinate(_maze.PlayerStartCoords.Row, _maze.PlayerStartCoords.Column, 2);`

to

`_player.transform.localPosition = RemapTileCoordinate(_maze.PlayerStartCoords.Row, _maze.PlayerStartCoords.Column, 50);`

In the Unity Editor the code worked. I originally spawned flush with the floor and now I correctly spawn way above the floor and fall down to the floor.
[image]

But when I build the project, the new code doesn't work. The build result still contains the parameter `2` in `RemapTileCoordinate` instead of `10` which I changed it to.

Here's a screenshot of me building the project
[image]

And here's me running the build result
[image]

Why can't Unity's build functionality see that I changed the `2` to a `50`?

Comment: Didn't you change it to `50` though ;)

Comment: Oh my bad haha I meant 50, I will change it now.